# User leaderboard filter bug

Tags: bug

So, I just discovered that the quarter and month filters (currently year selected in the image) both do the same thing aka filter by month. If you hover over the labels, it will tell you the range and you can see, right now it is set to 2013-04-01 to today in both cases.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not actually a bug this, its working as intended.

Jan-Feb-Mar is quarter one. We're now in April so Quarter two will be Apr-May-Jun

Basically, you won't see any difference between Quarter and Month until May, because the quarter figure will then have more months data to go on.

You'd find that if you check on Jan 5th you'd get the same results for Week, Month Quarter and Year.

Comment: Oh ... Shit ...

Comment: Feel free to delete this ;)